# Selecting the value of "type" attribute of a xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

What would be the syntax to select the values of "type" attribute  with value='True' for the below xml using xslt.

```
 <xyz groupId="1" answered="True">
    <add type="aa" code="1" value="True" />
    <add type="bb" code="2" value="False"/>
    <add type="cc" code="3" value="False"/>    
  </xyz>
```

Here I need to select the values-

aa
bb
cc

Is there any way out?
Please help.

Comment: ohh yeah sryy only aa in the above case.

Answer (score 0):

If you were indeed asking for an XSLT solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="add[@value='True']">
        <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
aa
```

As you can see, this differs from your expected output because the value of a `@type` attribute is only selected if the `@value` attribute is "True".

Comment: <xsl:template match="/">  
  <Options>  
   <xsl:copy-of select="xyz/add[@value='True']/@type"/>    
                </Options>
  </xsl:template> I am trying to use this but it is not working. Option is written bcoz it some thing predifend in my code. The values are used as options somewhere. But even ur code is notw working dont you think we need to use //xyz/add[@value='True'] but even after this it is not working.

Comment: Any other ideas plz??